# How can I prevent 16 digit numbers from being logged by nlog?

Tags: nlog

I want to filter out any 16 concurrent numerical digits from any log files. For example if my log message originally is:

`"you blah 01234567890123456 foo"`

I want it to only log:

`"you blah  foo"`

I do not know what to implement as it looks like filters prevent entire messages from being logged. I want to alter the message to be logged before it is logged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [replace layout render](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Replace-Layout-Renderer) to wrap your `$message` in your target layouts, which

> Replaces a string in the output of another layout with another string.

Using the following config:

```
<targets>
    <target xsi:type="Console" name="console" 
            layout="${replace:searchFor=\\d\{17,17\}\\s:replaceWith=:regex=true:inner=${message}}"/>
</targets>
```

and the following logging code

```
var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Info("you blah 01234567890123456 foo");
```

This is what is how the console output looks like:

> you blah foo

Because you can use any regex you can play with the config in order to correctly remove or keep the white spaces around the numbers, just watch for the encoding of the special characters.